# Understanding uplift in A/B testing

Tags: usability, usability-testing, marketing, features, ab-testing

Let's say we have a(n) **(positive) outcome rate** which we try to optimize.

Features affects this outcome.

In a test, we find that users that used a specific feature X have a higher positive outcome rate than users that have not used this feature.

What is then the meaning of *[uplift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_modelling)* regarding to the positive outcome rate? Concretely, how would one measure what the uplift in the positive outcome rate would be if all new users started using feature X?

Example:

- Nb users with positive outcome: 10
- Nb users with positive outcome with feature X: 8
- Nb users with positive outcome without feature X: 2
- Nb new users: 5
- Nb new users with feature X and thus a positive outcome: 3
- Nb new users with feature X without positive outcome: 2

What is then the uplift in the positive outcome if all new users would use feature X?

Comment: I think you need to make this a little clearer - your title says: Understanding Uplift in A/B Testing, yet the example makes no reference to A or B.

Comment: Basically what I meant was that a feature X has been implemented and now we want to check whether that feature positively enhances the positive outcome rate. I.e. is there an uplift when users use this feature? That's the A/B testing part.

Comment: Your example is a little confusing:-) Nb = Number? I don't understand why you are mentioning new users here.

Comment: Number indeed. Well I am looking into understanding what the impact would be if all New users would use feature X. In the current data there were 5 new users and of them 3 had implemented a feature X and thus a positive outcome. Now, if we were to make a forecast, what could this data tell us?

Comment: The whole point of an A/B test is to measure current vs new - it is not a forecasting measure. Obviously you can make a prediction (scientific or not) and then see if the prediction comes true in  the A/B. This is why I was confused by the question.

Comment: Right, but let me rephrase one more time. Let's say we have two groups: one that uses feature X (group A) and another one that does not use this feature (group B). And we have a positive outcome that influences a success rate which we try to enhance. In this case, Is the "uplift" of this feature then simply the difference between the success rate of group A and B (success_rate_A - success_rate_B)?

Comment: So this is two A/B tests - The first is positive outcome with feature (comparing current to new users) and the other A/B test is positive outcome without feature (comparing current user to new users), Correct?

Comment: Yes and no. I am not sure whether to compare current with new users. But the idea is to see the impact on the success rate for ALL users if EVERY NEW USER uses feature X

Comment: I am even more confused about what you are looking to achieve, especially as you said "In a test, we find that users that used a specific feature X have a higher positive outcome rate than users that have not used this feature." This strongly suggests the comparison is of the outcome rate between users who use the feature and those who do not. This does not sound like it is an A/B test (your title)

Comment: Probably I missed the point on the A/B testing. But I think what it boils down to is whether we can say that uplift is the difference in the success rates of those two group?

Comment: You have a current outcome rate. You have two groups. One group has used the system, the other group is using it for the first time, so you can compare the group's outcome rate. However, I don't think you will learn much from this comparison, e.g. new users will be worse than existing users simply because they are unfamiliar with the solution.

Comment: The point here is a single metric on its own cannot tell you very much even if the user groups are different. Typically A/B testing is used when you are comparing a current feature to a new redesigned feature, where the single metric is now being compared between the two version of your feature. It doesn't sound like you are redesigning anything.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking "the (subset of) people that use X have a higher success rate, so how much higher would the success rate be if all users used X?" But -- and this may depend on what the feature is -- it may be that those users using X _need_ to use it, but those who aren't using X have no need to use it, so "making" them use it would likely not affect their success (or might even lower it).

Answer (score 2):

Optimization tools usually give more statistics than the uplift %. Some will even tell you how many days/weeks the test should run given your current traffic, current conversion rate, and expected uplift.

The two most important things to take note of are the **Confidence Level**, and **Margin of Error**.

This usually uses a statistical measurement like Student's T-Test (or similar depending on the software) and can be translated as follows:

**Assumptions:**

- Version B gets 5% uplift when compared to a Control/Default group.
- There is a 10% margin of error.
- We use a 90% confidence level.

**Translation:**

In 90% of cases (our chosen confidence level) if you continue to run the experiment for infinite time, Version B (when compared to the control), will get between 4.5% - 5.5% more conversions. Because +/- 10% of a 5% increase is 0.5%.

So it's possible that some times people will convert above or below that range, but 90% of the time we have observed the increase which we can (hopefully) say is due to the change we introduced (our Version B vs. the Control group).

Hope this helps!